# MySQL - query to show guests with same last_name + booking_date

Tags: mysql

I have a guest table and a booking table and I am attempting to query how to find guests who share the same last names with the same booking date.

The result should output their last_name and first_names without any duplicate results.

```
SELECT g1.first_name, 
       g2.first_name,
       g1.last_name, 
       b1.booking_date,
       b2.booking_date
FROM guest g1 JOIN booking b1 ON g1.id=b1.booking_id 
JOIN guest g2 JOIN booking b2 ON g2.id=b2.booking_id
WHERE g1.last_name = g2.last_name AND g1.id<>g2.id AND b1.booking_date=b2.booking_date;
```

When I run this, I get back the empty set.

Where am I going wrong?[image: ERD]

The desired output should look something like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| last_name | first_name | booking_date|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| Smith     | George     |  2016-09-11 |
| Smith     |  Adam      |  2016-09-11 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

There should be no duplicate results.

Comment: Provide a fiddle with some test data and desured output.

Comment: `g1.id=b1.booking_id` looks "wrong".

Comment: @RickJames how so

Comment: *The desired output should look something like this* Provide source data for THIS output.

Comment: Re: _how so_ -- presumably `guest.id` should be matching `booking.guest_id`, not `booking.booking_id`, if one were to interpret your ERD literally.

Comment: @JS - If `booking` and `guest` are 1:1, why have two separate tables?  If many:1, I would expect the `JOIN` to be on `guest_id`.

Comment: @RickJames you are correct, the JOIN should be on guest_id

Answer (score 1):

**To fix SELECT**

Change

```
g1.id<>g2.id
```

to

```
g1.id < g2.id
```

to avoid getting exactly 2 copies of each result row.

**To follow output:**

```
SELECT  g3.first_name, x.last_name, x.booking_date
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT  g2.last_name, g2.id, b2.booking_date
            FROM  guest AS g2
            JOIN  booking b2  ON g2.id = b2.guest_id
    ) AS x
    JOIN  guest   AS g3  ON g3.last_name = x.last_name
                        AND g3.id = x.id
```

Comment: How would this work for cases where there was more than 2 people with the same last name for the same date?

Comment: @JoeW - I _think_ you would get 3 lines for 3 people; 6 lines for 4 people, etc.  (N*(N-1))/2 -- there are 6 "combinations" of 4 people taken 2 at a time.  No output rows would be duplicated.  However, _based on your `SELECT`_, 6 rows is "right".  OTOH, _based on your sample output_, you want 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

@RickJames created the solution. The JOIN ON clause was on the wrong field. The correct answer should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       g1.last_name,
       g1.first_name,
       g2.first_name,
       b2.booking_date
FROM guest g1 JOIN booking b1 ON g1.id=b1.guest_id
JOIN guest g2 JOIN booking b2 ON g2.id=b2.guest_id
WHERE g1.last_name = g2.last_name AND g1.id < g2.id AND b1.booking_date=b2.booking_date;
```

DISTINCT removes the duplicate result in the output.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` and the `<` were two ways to solve the same problem.  (The `<` is more efficient.)